# Git. Merge other's local changes into own repository

Tags: git

Some time ago I acquired a project from a third-party I don't have impact on.
I committed the `Version 1` I received into my repository without changes.

After that I made changes into it's files and committed them too.

Recently I received an archive with updates made by the third-party mentioned above.

They started from `Version 1` I received before and made it `Version 2` changing a lot of files.

**Now I need:**

1. Keep track of third-party changes (`Version 1 -> Version 2`).
2. Conveniently merge their changes into my project.

**I tried the following:**

1. Create an `update` branch from the `master` branch initial commit of `Version 1`.
2. Push the updates I received into `update` branch.
3. Merge `update` into `master.

**This way has drawbacks I'd like to solve:**

Let's say I have changed `file_A` some time ago.

`file_A` has also been changed by the third-party and their changes are marked with the most recent date in my repository because I just committed them.

When I merge the branches some of their changes can just overwrite my ones because they don't conflict (their commit is made after mine).

The only thing I can do is to revise all the changed files manually.

I suppose making the `Version 2` commit be in the past (right after `Version 1`) would solve my problem by raising conflicts in every file changed by both of us.

All in all, I think marking all files where changes were made by both of us as conflicts would work in my case but any advise is appreciated.

*Here's a visual graph of what I have now:*

```
master: V1---A1---A2
          \
update:    ------------V2
```

*What I want to achieve:*

```
master: V1---V2---A1'---A2'
```

Comment: `git rebase` did the trick for me. It duplicated all my commits prior to update but hey could be squashed into one commit using the `squash` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

First

```
git fetch --all
```

then

```
git rebase nameofremotebranch
```

Your local branch will be updated with the new commits from the remote and your commits will be put on top of everything. Unless they conflict. Then research interactive rebase, it will take some manual work.

I assume you already did

git remote add (etc)

and added the remote.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell please if all of my comments will be on top?
Actually I don't need all, I need only the ones after the `Version 1` was pushed

Comment: Yes when you rebase, you remove all your commits, you update everything and catch up with the remote, then you put everything you have done on top of everything (updated). If something conflicts all you have to do is rebase -i and start a long manual process where you can drop, edit (amend) or otherwise tweak your commits